# Angular how to use $save with WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a resource service with the following code

```
function productResource($resource) {    
return $resource("http://localhost/api/product/:id", null,
{
   'update':{method:'PUT'}
});
```

I have a route set up for editing products like this

```
  .state("productEdit", 
  {
   abstract: true,
   url: "/products/edit/:id",
   templateUrl: "app/products/productEditView.html",
   controller: "productEditCtrl as vm",
   resolve: {
      productResource: "productResource",
      product: function (productResource, $stateParams) {
        var id = $stateParams.id;
        return productResource.get({id: id}).$promise;
    }
}
})
```

My controller looks like this

```
    function productEditCtrl(product,  productResource, $state) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.product=  product;
    if (vm.product.data && vm.product.data.id) {
        vm.title = "Edit: " + vm.product.data.cusip;
    }
    else {
        vm.title = "New product"
    }
    vm.submit = function(){
    vm.product.$save(
            function (data) {
                toastr.success("Save Successful");
            }
        );
    };
```

The Web API returns a dynamic object with the following structure

```
public class ResponseResult {
public dynamic Data { get; set; }
public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
public bool DataIsValid
}
```

The webAPI controller action looks like this

```
[Route("api/product/{productId}")]
[HttpGet]
public dynamic FindproductById(Guid productId)
{            
     productDto productDto = this.productManager.FindproductById(productId);
     return new ResponseResult(productDto, HttpStatusCode.OK, productDto.ValidationResults, null);
}

[Route("api/product")]
[HttpPost]
public dynamic Createproduct(productDto productDto)
{

   Verify.IsNotNull("product dto", productDto);

   if (productDto.Id == Guid.Empty)
   {
     this.productManager.Createproduct(productDto);
   }

   return new ResponseResult(productDto, HttpStatusCode.OK,    productDto.ValidationResults, null);
}
```

My problem is when i call the $save function, it sends null product data back as the $save is tied to ResponseResult and i need to send the product data back to the webapi. I somehow need to tie the product data coming back from webapi to vm.product so when i call vm.product.$save, it works. How can i do that?

Comment: How does the web api products controller/action look?

Comment: Martin, I added the controller code in the question

Comment: Did you create an empty constructor for `ResponseResult` ? I had issues in the past where creating an empty constructor was missing.

Comment: Simcha, empty constructor didnt make any difference. The issue is not the web api but rather how $resource works. The whole code works fine if change the return type of the GET in the web api to ProductDto instead of a ResponseResult.

Comment: Why are you having a return type of `dynamic` instead of `IHttpActionResult` with the latter you could use `return Created<T>(string location, T content)` if you wanted to return some content or just do a `return Ok()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following setup when resolving a state using `$resource`.

I have a `CustomerService` which is injected into the resolve:

```
angular
    .module("app.customer")
    .factory("CustomerService", CustomerService);

function CustomerService($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/customers/:id", { id: "@customerId" })
}
```

My route config looks like this:

```
.state("customers.details", {
    url: "/{id}/",
    templateUrl: "/app/customers/customers.details.html",
    controller: "CustomersController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    resolve: {
        customer: function (CustomerService, $stateParams) {
            return CustomerService.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
        }
    }
})
```

The `customer` is injected into the `CustomersController` where it allows me to do both `.$save` and `.$update` on the `customer`.

Your web api controller could look like this:

```
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(CustomerCreateCommand model)
{
    var customer = await customerRepository.InsertAsync(model);

    return Created<CustomerViewModel>("/api/customers/" + customer.Id, MapToViewModel<CustomerViewModel>(customer));
}
```

In this case, where you don't have control over the API and it's not returning the expected entities the `$resource` won't work out of the box.

The problem your facing is that your getting a different entity type than the one you wish to send back to the API. You need to unwrap the `data` field, because that's what the API is expecting when doing a `POST`.

You could write your submit function like the below, where you create a new resource with the values from your `vm.product.data` which should map to servers `productDto` class:

```
vm.submit = function() {
  new productResource(vm.product.data).$save(function () {  
    // saved successfully
  });
};
```

Comment: Martin, thanks for the suggestion. But unfortunately, i don't control the API and hence cannot change it.